# Isekai manga in which the main character saves the elf continent/island from humans

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

The main character (MC) is summoned to another world.  The king is greedy and the MC leaves the kingdom.  He finds an elf who needs help and takes her to the elf continent which is located south of the country he was summoned to.  They arrive at the country and she talks to the elders.  He wants to learn magic from them.  They talk and one of the elders teaches him magic.  During their stay on the continent, the humans attack via ships and there are massive amounts of ships.   The MC runs through the trees to the coast where the enemy is and takes out all the ships and people invading the elf continent.